# Meteor mongo: sync fields across collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a meeting document like this:

```
{
    "name":"Meeting Name",
    "uuid":"NYoc2aL6",
    "participants":[
        {
            "id":"JLKGZnfFkGvX9DHgz",
            "status":"joined",
            "name":"Guest 03"
        },
        {
            // newly invited user, user hasn't logged in with invite url yet
            "id":"",
            "status":"invited",
            "name":"email@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need to synchronize the 'name' field with the name in the Users collection.  Is there an automatic way to do this, like at the database level, or am I stuck with manually updating in every place that the name is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common pattern in Meteor. You can use the [matb33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) package to "hook" the collection update to synchronize the shared value(s). This should be done server-side of course so you don't have to worry about some of the related documents not being available to you.

Example:

```
Meteor.users.after.update((userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options)=>{
  if ( fieldNames.indexOf('profile.name') > -1 ){ // the name was changed
    Meetings.update({ 'participants.id': doc._id },
      { $set: { 'participants.name': doc.profile.name }},
      { multi: true });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "automatic" way to do this that I know of in Mongo or Meteor.  However, why not take the common fields out of your document and just link the ID?  This is known as "Database Normalization", which is a process by which you remove redundant data from your tables (collections in Mongo) to prevent these sorts of problems.

Comment: database normalization ends up in increased fetching time. if you really have to look up all the usernames again and again it would be better imho to store the names into the document. so it depends. will he save space or time on retrieving data

Comment: This is where you'd have to get more in-depth into how the app was working.  Adding to the document would decrease load times and increase save times and space (for duplicated fields), as well as increase code complexity and potential issues keeping things synced.  Linking via shared ID would remove the complexity of sync code and decrease the space, but also it adds more collections and decreases the speed of reads.  It could also increase inserts/updates, depending on how those flow. Knowing what is more important for the app is helpful in these situations.

Comment: In my case, it's for more specific reasons having to do with optional sequences of user experience, i.e. in some cases the user would be added to a meeting but not have an actual user account yet, so no `user.profile.name` field.  Normally, of course I would try to normalize everything.

Comment: Right, but if you did want to "normalize", you could have an Attendee collection where the stored documents were either the firstname/lastname/emailaddress or simply a link to the User object, sort of like polymorphism.  In this way, if the Attendee is a registered user, it links the meeting to an Attendee, which then links to their account, but if not it links the meeting to an Attendee.  If later the user signs up, which would most likely include providing an email, you could then flip their Attendee to be linked to their userid.  Again, it all depends on what you feel comfortable with.

Comment: All true. I went ahead and 'answered' my question with an approach that uses `observeChanges`, since that was the spirit of what I was originally looking for. Now as for if that's a GOOD idea... ;)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about using the `observeChanges`.  Sadly, I have used it before myself, but not to sync collection data but to auto-populate some agregate data into separate collections and also in a [POC](https://github.com/mbabauer/meteor_publicationsDemo) for a talk on how pub/sub works.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done 'automatically' by observing changes on the users db:

```
var usersCursor = Meteor.users.find();
usersCursor.observeChanges({"changed":function(id, fields){
    if(fields.profile.name){
        ... do whatever needs to be done ...
    }
}});
```